# Does DNS NS record invalidate session cookies?

Tags: cookies, web, dns, cross-domain

My website allows users to use subdomains as their own site, and I use cross-domain cookies for global authentication: users can log in via **www.mysite.com** to get access to **user1.mysite.com**.

Now some users may want to have their own domain name, they can bind a domain name **www.abc.com** to his subdomain **user1.mysite.com** with a NS record added via the domain name provider. My question is: Will this cause log in to fail from **www.mysite.com**? Or in other words, is the cookie shared between **www.abc.com** and **user1.mysite.com** ?

I cannot allow users to log in from www.abc.com, for 2 reasons:

1. users could visit many subdomains of mysite, I want the cookie to be shared.
2. I used Oauth as a sign-in option, and oauth only allows 1 redirection url after authenticatoin.

Answer (score 0):

NS records have nothing to do with web authentication, they are used purely for DNS resolution.  Putting in an NS record at www.abc.com that refers to your name servers for mysite.com doesn't work at all unless you are hosting www.abc.com.  And I sure hope you're not trying to hijack www.abc.com.  The DIsney Corporation would not be happy with you. :)

If you mean something else, please clarify with a better example (i.e., show NS records with name and target).